# Getting error while fetching a specific object using graphql

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

This is my Schema for GraphQL :

```
type Link {
  url: String!
  description: String!
}

type Query {
  allLinks: [Link]
  myLinks: [Link]
  link(url:String!):Link
}

type Mutation {
    createLink(url:String! , description:String!):Link
}

schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}
```

Following is the Java Pojo for Query , Link & GraphQLRootResolver :

```
public class Link {
    private final String url;
    private final String description;

    public Link(String url, String description) {
        this.url = url;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Query implements GraphQLRootResolver {
    private final LinkRepository linkRepository;

    public Query(LinkRepository linkRepository) {
        this.linkRepository = linkRepository;
    }

    public List<Link> allLinks() {
        return linkRepository.getAllLinks();
    }

    public List<Link> myLinks() {
        return linkRepository.getAllLinks();
    }

    public Link link(String url) {
        return linkRepository.getLink(url);
    }
}
```

This is the implementation for the Resolver :

```
public List<Link> getAllLinks() {
    return links;
}

public void saveLink(Link link) {
    links.add(link);
}

public Link getLink(String str) {
    Link link = null;
    try {
        link = new Link(str, dashboardService.getDashboard(str));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return link;
}
```

When i use the following query to fetch data for particular url based then i am getting following error :

```
http://localhost:8000/graphql?query={link(url:%22d_comp1%22){url}}
```

Error i am getting :

```
{"data":{"link":null},"errors":[{"message":"Internal Server Error(s) while executing query"}]}
```

As i am new to GraphQL , Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this as the query which i was using to fetch the data was wrong.
Correct query would be:

```
query={link(url:"d_comp_1"){url,description}}
```